# Where is brand & model information stored in an output device?

Tags: windows, usb, drivers, mouse

For example, why does Windows show me "SanDisk Ultra USB 3.0 USB Device" string when I plug in my flash drive to my computer?

Or, why does Windows show me "GXT 922 Gaming Mouse" string when I plug in my mouse to my computer?

Can I access and/or re-write/modify this information via a low level language such as Assembly or Hex?

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: How about, device manager, device properties, details, Hardware-id's? If you see PCI\VEN_###&DEV_####.... google that string and you'll find the device online too. Windows can query the device by plug and play. If not found, windows won't know until you install the drivers yourself in which case it adds the string for that id string from your driver package.

Comment: @LPChip Then how does Windows access PCI\VEN... information even if I am offline? How does Windows know that it is a Sandisk drive, but not Kingston or Lexar?

Comment: "How does Windows know that it is a SanDisk drive, but not Kingston or Lexar?" - This information is stored on the device.

Comment: @Ramhound I mean, where is the location of this information? EEPROM or something like chip?

Comment: Windows has an offline database that translates the PCI\VEN_... information, called a driver information store. This database is maintained through windows update if you allow driver installations there or when installing vendor drivers. The ability to send a name is possible with generic PnP driver architecture.

Answer (score 4):

> For example, why does Windows show me "SanDisk Ultra USB 3.0 USB Device" string when I plug in my flash drive to my computer?
>
> Or, why does Windows show me "GXT 922 Gaming Mouse" string when I plug in my mouse to my computer?

Primarily, Windows receives those from the USB controller in the device. Each USB device reports its "device descriptor", which includes its vendor ID and product ID (the numeric VID&PID values) as well as text versions of the manufacturer name and product name, in addition to what *kind* of device it is and what "interfaces" it supports.

The device's USB controller would store it in some kind of EEPROM or flash memory, but this can vary from device to device and isn't revealed to the host system – the OS only gets the fully formatted USB device descriptor, doesn't actually read the raw memory.

But because these labels are of limited length, Windows also allows drivers to override them with nicer labels if needed (mapping the VID & PID from the descriptor to labels from the driver). Lots of devices have .inf-only "drivers" that don't really install a driver per se, but only provide better labels for devices (this can also be seen for PCI devices, which can't even report names). Normally those are obtained from Windows Update these days, but a few such driver packages may still be bundled offline with Windows itself.

More details:

- https://www.beyondlogic.org/usbnutshell/usb5.shtml
- In video form (something I watched last month): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N0O5Uwc3C0o – at around 14 minutes, all the discovery requests are explained in detail.

> Can I access and/or re-write/modify this information via a low level language such as Assembly

Sometimes, possibly, but the language won't help you much. For two different reasons:

1. Low-level language: In every modern OS, programs have no special hardware access *regardless* of the language they're written in. That is, the OS either lets processes do something (use I/O registers, access raw memory, etc) or it does not, but the language doesn't help with that. And on the other hand, what you *can* do in assembly language, you can also do in C and similar.
2. The device has to *support* editing this data, most devices simply don't. The whole USB descriptor might simply be stored in one-time-programmable ROM that you physically can't alter once it's been written. In addition, there is no standard command for that – normally it's something only the manufacturer needs to do.

   (For certain devices, there *may* be leaked manufacturing tools that use "hidden" commands to rebrand the device – especially for USB sticks, I've used at least two different tools in the past, but each was made only for a very specific series of USB flash storage chips. I really wouldn't expect anything similar to exist for mice or printers...)

> ...or Hex?

That's not even a programming language. Hex doesn't *do* anything – it's literally just a different way of writing numbers.